# How not to set the user's email address in django social-auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I have django social-auth installed (from omab) and the users have an email address in database that is the one I want to keep but when the users log in from facebook using social-auth, their email gets replaced by the one they have in their facebook account. I am not sure the settings are the one by default or not and cannot find how to stop this behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it, in the [pipeline](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html) the responsible for that is

```
social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details
```

I just removed it from the pipeline and now the details like email address and name are left to the user to fill.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried **SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS**? :)

From the manual:

> The update_user_details pipeline processor will set certain fields on
> user objects, such as email. Set this to a list of fields you only
> want to set for newly created users:
>
> > > SOCIAL_AUTH_PROTECTED_USER_FIELDS = ['email',]
>
> Also more extra values will be stored if defined. Details about this
> setting are listed below in the OpenId and OAuth sections.

Comment: today I would definitely do that, but back in the days that was another story :) Protected fields was not introduced yet.

Comment: Yeah, I know.

I was trying to solve it yesterday and I almost went for glarrain's solution. Then I found this settings in the manual. Just put it here in case someone TL;DR the manual:)

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting my solution (update user details, not overwrite them) so it may help someone. Based on `pipeline.user.update_user_details` I coded the following:

```
def fill_user_details(backend, details, response, user, is_new=False, *args,
                        **kwargs):
    """Fills user details using data from provider, without overwriting
    existing values.

    backend: Current social authentication backend
    details: User details given by authentication provider
    response: ?
    user: User ID given by authentication provider
    is_new: flag

    source: social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details
    """
    # Each pipeline entry must return a dict or None, any value in the dict
    # will be used in the kwargs argument for the next pipeline entry.
    #
    # If any function returns something else beside a dict or None, the
    # workflow will be cut and the value returned immediately, this is useful
    # to return HttpReponse instances like HttpResponseRedirect.

    changed = False  # flag to track changes

    for name, value in details.iteritems():
        # do not update username, it was already generated
        if name in (USERNAME, 'id', 'pk'):
            continue

        # set it only if the existing value is not set or is an empty string
        existing_value = getattr(user, name, None)
        if value is not None and (existing_value is None or
                                  not is_valid_string(existing_value)):
            setattr(user, name, value)
            changed = True

    # Fire a pre-update signal sending current backend instance,
    # user instance (created or retrieved from database), service
    # response and processed details.
    #
    # Also fire socialauth_registered signal for newly registered
    # users.
    #
    # Signal handlers must return True or False to signal instance
    # changes. Send method returns a list of tuples with receiver
    # and it's response.
    signal_response = lambda (receiver, response): response
    signal_kwargs = {'sender': backend.__class__, 'user': user,
                     'response': response, 'details': details}

    changed |= any(filter(signal_response, pre_update.send(**signal_kwargs)))

    # Fire socialauth_registered signal on new user registration
    if is_new:
        changed |= any(filter(signal_response,
            socialauth_registered.send(**signal_kwargs)))

    if changed:
        user.save()
```

Comment: Hi. How exactly do I go about implementing the solution you've posted above in my Django application? Where exactly should the above piece of code go?

Comment: @ArpitRai If you have a relatively new version of `social-auth` I recommed you use Zhe's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/16267281/556413)